# Path like menu item - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I'm making use of [Siyamed's](https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu/) menu item in my app.. I would like to place the menu item in the bottom center of the screen.. and when I click on it, the child items should surround the center icon. Any ideas on how to start?

Comment: I had to fork the project to customize things. satellite-menu is great but hard to customize by default (I find).

Comment: @shkschneider does it mean that it is not possible to move the menu item from bottom-left to bottom-center? If so, are there any alternatives for the same?

Comment: you could. I just pointed out my personal experience about it. If you want to customize it further, you might need to fork it.

Comment: @shkschneider ahhh ok. will into the code. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you tried another implementation: [ArcMenu by daCapricorn](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu).

As the author [said on Google+](https://plus.google.com/107460592910747948011/posts):

If you want to put it align the screen bottom, you can set `alignparentbottom="true"` in xml and compute the `marginBottom` (it should be negative) programmatically.

*PS: I personnality ended up using ArcMenu library rather than SatelliteMenu for the same issue.*

Comment: Yeaah I also started using ArcMenu by daCapricorn. And I saw the comment by the author in Google+.. I added alignparentbottom="true" in the xml, but the menu didn't exactly align at the bottom.. It aligned say 20dp above the bottom.. did you resolve this problem? Can you please post the code?

Comment: I made a few changes, hope it might help you: https://github.com/shkschneider/android_ArcMenu/commit/abe5c13e244ead885183a7f21748109f844b8f37

Comment: I added "android:layout_marginBottom="-80dp" in the xml file and it the icon aligned exactly in the bottom-center.. since I hardcoded the value it doesn't work in all the phones.. Any idea on how to calculate it??

BTW I saw the github link that you posted.. but couldn't understand where exactly you changed the code.. Could you please point the file?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi, I'm able to resolve the problem.. After setting `android:layout_marginBottom` to some negative value it aligned exactly at the bottom center. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Feel free to +1 and accept as answer. Glad you solved your issue.